# Protocol to be used to make microcontroller to work as mouse

Tags: microcontroller, usb, computers, protocol, hid

I'am Doing a "**Wireless mouse using data glove**" . In this user wears a Hand glove equipped with sensors, microcontroller & transmitter. I could detect left & right movement of hand & i could detect clicks & transmit them using transmitter.

The receiving module consists of a receiver, microcontroller and receiver should be connected to USB of computer. Now, Which protocol i should use to indicate the computer to move mouse pointer accordingly ?

Comment: what options do you have?

Comment: You want it to act as a HID device so that the operating system doesn't need special drivers to use it as a basic mouse.

Comment: USB Human Interface Device (HID). USB HID for mice is standardized, and depending on your microcontroller you probably have examples for a usb hid mouse (Some Pic or Msp430 do). See http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_5.htm

Comment: Implementing your own 'mouse' is the ideal, but easiest of all may be to connect hardware inputs to an existing mouse.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments the HID (Human Interface Device) class is what you're looking for to operate as a mouse without any special drivers. You can find the full specifications at  [HID Related Specifications](http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DM164127) at USB.org although they're fairly heavy reading.

Your best bet to get started is probably to buy a development board that contains a USB compatible microcontroller and has a vendor supported USB stack available. Both the AVR and PIC series have one available if you're after a small 8-bit solution, but many vendors provide the same.

As an example recently I purchased a Microchip [Low Pin Count USB Dev kit](http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DM164127) that came with complete working examples that made getting started easy. While I was using the CDC class I noticed it also included an example for a HID mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, but mostly for completeness reasons, you could also implement the PS/2 protocol, given your consuming device (a computer) has a PS/2 port. PS/2 might be a bit more straight forward.